# This lemma slows down FStar/Emacs

Tags: fstar

It takes about 2 minutes for FStar to prove this lemma and what is worse, Emacs becomes intolerably slow as long as it's present. Other, apparently more complicated lemmas do not cause this problem.

```
let lemma_1 (n: nat) (m: nat) : Lemma (n <= m || n > 0) = ()
```

Is there an Emacs/FStar option relevant to this matter?

Comment: Is there something in your overall context (eg, due to other lemmas/smt patterns etc.) that might be causing the slowdown? Are you on a recent enough version of F*? For me, the lemma goes through in under a second (both from Emacs interactive mode and from terminal). Could you post a complete file that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've reviewed the article at https://github.com/FStarLang/fstar-mode.el and found it's Emacs bug 21022 which still seems to be present in 26.3. prettify-symbols-mode resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it is fixed! You should add that comment as an answer to yourself and mark it as accepted to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article at github.com/FStarLang/fstar-mode.el mentions this issue as an Emacs bug.
It seems to be present in Emacs 26.3. M-x prettify-symbols-mode resolves it.